# Training FRCNN tensorflow2

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to train FRCNN on ham10000
I found [this](https://github.com/eleow/tfKerasFRCNN) repository which implement FRCNN with tf.1
I can't use tf.1 in colab and using diffrent version of tf caused some problem for me

library I used for training FRCNN defined model in this way
 `self.model_classifier = Model([img_input, roi_input], classifier)`
when classifier is
        `classifier = _classifier( feature_network, roi_input, num_rois, nb_classes=num_classes, trainable=True, base_net_type=base_net_type)`
when I try to train model with fit_generator in library I get NonType is not callable error
I found that reason for this error is that model_classifiertrain_function in None , I think the reason is that fit is not called on model,I tried to change Force argument in make_train_function in training.py file in tensorflow and everythin worked out but I think this change might cause problem to overall model performance